# How to create pivot in read csv file with scala

Tags: java, scala, csv, pivot

i have get problem. I will create code scala read csv file and dont create result in pivot. Any Solution..??

File csv:

```
Div,Person
A,Excel
A,Job
A,Bob
B,Alice
B,Anna
```

Output:

```
Div|Person
A|Excel,Job,Bob
B|Alice,Anna
```

My Code:

```
object Tes {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    var result : List[Person] = Nil
    var strings = StringBuilder.newBuilder

    val bufferedSource = io.Source.fromFile("src/main/resources/config/person.csv")
    for (line <- bufferedSource.getLines) {
      val cols = line.split(",")
      val div = cols.apply(0)
      val name = cols.apply(1)

    }
    bufferedSource.close
  }

}
```

Model:

```
case class Person(div: String, person: String)
```

How to create code scala like output..?? Thanks.

Comment: Is this a homework?

Comment: @mpetruska no homework but i get problem this in scala.

Comment: So, what is the exact problem?

Comment: @mpetruska i will get print by col in my code val div = cols.apply(0) but i can't print like output. A|Excel,Job,Bob. I can output print cols by read csv A,Excel
A,Job

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile("src/main/resources/config/person.csv")

source.getLines()
  .map(_.split(","))
  .foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Seq[String]])({
    case (map, Array(div, name)) =>
      map + (div -> (map.get(div) match {
        case None => Seq(name)
        case Some(seq) => seq :+ name
      }))
  })
  .foreach({ case (div, names) => println(div + "|" + names.mkString(",")) })

source.close()
```

If you want to make it a more efficient you can use mutable collections during the fold.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. code is run well.. Ok i will implement mutable collection in my model.

Answer (score 0):

Oke i will get finish code to write csv in model. Before thanks to @Nils.

My code:

```
import java.io.{File, PrintWriter}
import scala.io.Source.fromFile

object Tes {

  //Model
  case class Person(div: String, person: String)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val csv_path = "src/main/resources/config/person.csv"
    val filePath = "src/main/resources/config/result-person.csv"

    val process = pivot(csv_path)
    println(process)

    val result = saveFlattenToFile(process,filePath)

  }

  def pivot(path: String): List[Person] = {

    //Initial
    var result : List[Person] = Nil

    val source = fromFile(path)

    source.getLines().drop(1)
      .map(_.split(","))
      .foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Seq[String]])({
        case (map, Array(div, name)) =>
          map + (div -> (map.get(div) match {
            case None => Seq(name)
            case Some(seq) => seq :+ name
          }))
      })
      .foreach({ case (div, name) =>
        result = result ::: List(Person(div,name.mkString(",")))
        //println(channelName + "|" + channel.mkString(","))
      })

    source.close()
    //Output
    return result

  }

  def saveFlattenToFile(channels: List[Person], filePath: String): Boolean = {

    //Initial
    var result = false

    //Process
    if (channels.size > 0) {
      val writer = new PrintWriter(new File(filePath))
      writer.write("Div|Person\n")
      for (model <- channels) writer.write(model.div + "|" + model.person +  "\n")
      writer.close()
      result = true
    }

    //Output
    return result
  }

}
```